# JBoss6 AS EJB3StandaloneBootstrap & EJB3StandaloneDeployer

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.1

currently i'am migrating a JBoss 4 project to JBoss 6. I do miss substitutes for the EJB3StandaloneDeployer and EJB3StandaloneBootstrap.

Are there any new sources which deliver the functionality of this two classes?

THX

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `EJB3StandaloneDeployer` and `EJB3StandaloneBootstrap` are replaced by the standard `EJBContainer` API. Here is an example:

```
// Instantiate an embeddable EJB container and search the
// JVM class path for eligible EJB modules or directories
EJBContainer ejbC = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();

// Get a naming context for session bean lookups
Context ctx = ejbC.getNamingContext();

// Retrieve a reference to the AccountBean using a
// portable global JNDI name (more on this later!)  
AccountBean ab = (AccountBean) 
    ctx.lookup("java:global/account/AccountBean");

// Test the account
Account a1 = ab.createAccount(1234);

...

// Shutdown the embeddable container
ejbC.close();
```

JBoss also started the [Arquillian](http://jboss.org/arquillian) that you might find interesting.

#### See also

- [TOTD #128: EJBContainer.createEJBContainer: Embedded EJB using GlassFish v3](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_128_ejbcontainer_createejbcontainer_embedded)
- The [Arquillian](http://jboss.org/arquillian) project
- The [Arquillian Community Space](http://community.jboss.org/en/arquillian/)